# How to approach the following excel file related issue

Tags: database, excel

We have a very large excel file that is produced every day by a batch process. We need to report what records were added and which records were removed compared to the file generated on the previous day. The challenge is that there is no sortable field in the list that we could use (such as a creation date), imagine for the sake of this test that there’s only First Name, Last Name and Email in the excel file, and that the ordering is not consistent from one day to the next.

Please let me know how should I approach this problem?

Comment: How large is "very large" - how many rows?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: All those fields can be sorted (alphabetically)

Comment: The simplest would be to use vlookups on a "key" that would be a concatenation of multiple fields. That involves making a few extra columns but it will work just fine. However, this is as manual a process as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it at a high level, you could do multiple things to get a diff from one file to another.

1. Use MS Access and write some code to import the daily Excel file and then run queries to compare one day to another.
2. Use SQL Server Express to do the same thing from point (1).
3. Write code to load an array of emails (as an example) in memory from today's Excel file.  Do the same with yesterday's file and then compare them in memory. Should be easy to see what's changed.
4. Write code to export the Excel files into CSV format and then use something like Python to quickly parse the files and give you the diffs.
5. You could even load two Excel files into one workbook and write VBA (code in Excel) to compare both sheets.

Tons of options.